# Projection onto Polyeder

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I know how to projects onto a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, but how to project a point $x$ onto an polyhedron given as the intersection of three halfspaces
$$
 \langle y_1, x \rangle \ge c_1 \mbox{ and }
 \langle y_2, x \rangle \ge c_2 \mbox{ and }
 \langle y_3, x \rangle \ge c_3?
$$

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no closed form for the projection of a point onto an arbitrary polyhedron. You must solve

$$min_z ||x-z||_2$$

$$ \langle y_i^T z\rangle \geq c_i , i=1,\ldots$$

For some special cases there might be particularly efficient algorithms (as for instance the unitary simplex).